# How to open a small window in non activity class in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog

I am trying to find a way to open a small window which along with a button in non activity class. Basically i tried to use this way:

```
public class Mytest{
 private Context context;
public Mytes(Context context)
{
  this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
 }

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create(); //Use context
    alertDialog.setTitle("Warning");
    alertDialog.setMessage("You are currently in a battle");
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    alertDialog.show();
```

but getting exception that

```
Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

I have seen a thread in which someone suggested to use activity instead of context. i have try with both way to set context into nonactivity class from my main activity:

```
mytest = new Mytest(MainActivity.this);
```

but it is not working. Any other solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to edit your constructor like this:

```
public Mytes(Context context) { 
this.context = context; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getApplicationContext(), just use ActivityName.this.